# How do I save and use camera images in python code in BGE?

Tags: python, game-engine

Say I'm in BGE and I'm running an artificial intelligent human that will see the room its in. In my code, I need the images from the 2 cameras in its eye sockets. How do I get camera images in my python (or external C++) code, to then be able to use in ex. in a Convolution Neural Network algorithm?

Comment: I can't really tell for sure from that question. Is it really giving the solution for getting a camera image into your code? My goal is to simulate a AI robot baby, that will see with its camera eyes. Then pass the rendered images through code algorithms.

Comment: I agree, this is a different question. This is in BGE where the BPY module (used in the "duplicate" solution) is not available.

Comment: Because this is closed, I can't write a full solution, but the things you need to look at are: bge.texture.ImageRender() to get an image from a BGE camera. Then you can refresh that into a numpy array to extract the data. If you want to, you can then pass that into PIL using Image.fromarray(). Once you're in PIL, you can do CV to your hearts content.